# Can't install Perl DBD module on Ubuntu (for Bugzilla)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, perl, bugzilla

Trying to install `bugzilla-4.2.2` on Ubuntu `12.04`. When I run `checksetup.pl` I get the following error:

```
YOU MUST RUN ONE OF THE FOLLOWING COMMANDS (depending on which database
you use):

PostgreSQL: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::Pg
MySQL: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::mysql
SQLite: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::SQLite
Oracle: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::Oracle

To attempt an automatic install of every required and optional module
with one command, do:

/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all
```

I have installed MySQL via XAMPP so I run:

```
/urs/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::mysql
```

And get the following error:

```
perl Makefile.PL --testuser=username

Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 479.
Can't find mysql_config. Use --mysql_config option to specify where mysql_config is located
Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 479.
Can't find mysql_config. Use --mysql_config option to specify where mysql_config is located
Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 479.
Can't find mysql_config. Use --mysql_config option to specify where mysql_config is located
Failed to determine directory of mysql.h. Use

perl Makefile.PL --cflags=-I<dir>

to set this directory. For details see the INSTALL.html file,
section "C Compiler flags" or type

perl Makefile.PL --help
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL  LIB="/opt/lampp/htdocs/bugzilla/4.2.2/bugzilla-4.2.2/lib" INSTALLMAN1DIR="/opt/lampp/htdocs/bugzilla/4.2.2/bugzilla-4.2.2/lib/man/man1" INSTALLMAN3DIR="/opt/lampp/htdocs/bugzilla/4.2.2/bugzilla-4.2.2/lib/man/man3" INSTALLBIN="/opt/lampp/htdocs/bugzilla/4.2.2/bugzilla-4.2.2/lib/bin" INSTALLSCRIPT="/opt/lampp/htdocs/bugzilla/4.2.2/bugzilla-4.2.2/lib/bin" INSTALLDIRS=perl]
CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.021.tar.gz
/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL  LIB="/opt/lampp/htdocs/bugzilla/4.2.2/bugzilla-4.2.2/lib" INSTALLMAN1DIR="/opt/lampp/htdocs/bugzilla/4.2.2/bugzilla-4.2.2/lib/man/man1" INSTALLMAN3DIR="/opt/lampp/htdocs/bugzilla/4.2.2/bugzilla-4.2.2/lib/man/man3" INSTALLBIN="/opt/lampp/htdocs/bugzilla/4.2.2/bugzilla-4.2.2/lib/bin" INSTALLSCRIPT="/opt/lampp/htdocs/bugzilla/4.2.2/bugzilla-4.2.2/lib/bin" INSTALLDIRS=perl -- NOT OK
Skipping test because of notest pragma
Running make install
Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
```

So then I tried `checksetup.pl`'s suggestion and ran:

```
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all
```

And it seems to have installed `DBD::SQLite` without any problems, but again I see a warning that says it's skipping tests because of `notest pragma`.

When I re-run `checksetup.pl` It shows 3 of the 4 original DB drivers in the "not found" list:

```
PostgreSQL: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::Pg
MySQL: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::mysql
Oracle: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::Oracle
```

So running it with `--all` seems to have installed the SQLite driver without any problems, but for some reason I can't seem to install the MySQL driver. Again I need MySQL because thats what XAMPP uses and because I prefer MySQL regardless. I have a feeling it has something to do with this `notest pragma` error. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just [install Bugzilla 4 from a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tamersaadeh/+archive/bugzilla) and save yourself a whole lot of trouble?

Comment: Hey thats not a bad idea @Michael Hampton (+1) - my only concern is that I've now extracted the bugzilla tarball, installed XAMPP (Apache, MySQL, etc.) and `--all` Perl modules... if I install one of those PPAs will there be any conflicts with what I've already installed? Or does Ubuntu know not to install dependencies that are already there?

Comment: Having installed XAMPP is a whole other issue, especially since Ubuntu repositories already include Apache, MySQL, PHP and virtually everything else you might need. I would have just gone with what's in the repos, unless there was a very good reason to do otherwise. It makes the software much easier to manage.

Comment: OK....so you're saying you **do** think I'm going to run into problems? If so, what's the easiest way to back out the changes from XAMPP and all the Perl modules?

Comment: Grab your Ubuntu CD, throw it in, and reinstall. :)

Comment: Hah....ok so that would be the easiest I suppose... any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I know it sounds possibly stupid to say, but as I just did this myself, it probably deserves a mention here.

If you get an error saying that make (or anything else that obviously should be available) isn't isn't available in the repos, and you're on a fresh install, **make sure you have run `sudo apt-get update`**. I did a fresh install an hour ago and was installing bugzilla and hadn't restarted or run `apt-get update` and freaked out when I didn't see make available.. ran `apt-get update`, then ran sudo `apt-get install make` and it installed no problems.

Hope this helps the sidetracked/forgetful people like me out there.